# Set default/restrict text formats based on node type

Tags: 8, input-formats

In Drupal 8 (not D7) as noted [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16036/how-do-you-set-a-default-input-text-format-per-content-type) How do you limit a text input to only specific content types/fields.

For example, I create a new input type here: admin/config/content/formats
and call it "blog_body" and I want it to be the only (or at least default) option for the body field on blog post node type. Preferably it is not available on other nodes too.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please let me know how to better ask this question.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239068/how-do-i-force-a-text-format-and-hide-the-format-selector-in-a-formatted-text-fi

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats